How to seal window frame and repair surrounding concrete?
I just moved in to an apartment, and it's great apart from a few things that need repair.
In the pictures linked below, how would I go about repairing or filling in the gaps in the concrete at the tops and sides of the frame, and also how would I seal the bottom of the frame with the windowsill?
https://imgur.com/a/TRT7RA8
For context, in case it's useful, this is a 20-year old ground-floor apartment in Ireland.
